# Seeing duplicate http requests in server logs

Tags: http, firefox, firebug, request, yslow

I have started a small django application in my machine. When i have seen the request logs I figured out that It is actually logging the same requests twice.

After a little investigation, I disabled all of my add-ons in my browser and tried. To my surprise i din't see duplicate requests in logs After that.

After some trials I found that, If YSlow and firebug are enabled, Browser is sending duplicate requests. Otherwise i see only a single request in logs.

My machine is centos. And firefox version is 2.0.0.11. Yslow 2.0.1 and firebug 1.3.0

Did any body see this sort of issue? Any ideas what's going on actually?

Comment: I'm seeing this happen with Firefox 4 beta6. I don't have either tool installed (firebug or yslow). I've seen other posts indicating that Firefox will do this as early as version 3.

Answer (score 2):

Firebug and YSlow sending a request again if you have auto analysing activated. 
Or if not, when you open the network tab or starting the YSlow analysing.

**Use the latest version of booth tools!**